# Initial condition of wave equation using d'Alembert's method

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

Consider wave equation:

> $u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}$

with initial conditions:

> $u(x,0) = f(x)$ , $u_t(x,0) = g(x)$

Using change of variables $\mu = x + ct$ and $\eta = x-ct$, we get $u_{\mu\eta} = 0$ and then $u(\mu , \eta) = F(\mu) + G(\eta)$.

> $u(x,t) = F(x+ct) + G(x-ct) \implies u_t(x,t) = cF'(x+ct) - cG'(x-ct)$

where primes denote derivative with respect to $x+ct$ and $x-ct$, respectively.

Choosing $t=0$, we get:

> $u_t(x,0) = cF'(x) - cG'(x)$

Here is the problem. If we integrate with respect to $x$ then $\int_{x_0}^{x}F'(\lambda)d\lambda = F(x) - F(x_0)$? We know that $F'$ means derivative with respect to $x+ct$ not $x$. So why that is true? I spent two hours and only got confused more and more.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. $\int_{x_0}^x F'(\lambda)d\lambda = F(x) - F(x_0)$ is just the FTC. Are you stuck on concluding how D'Alambert's formula is obtained?

Comment: @Dayton Here derivative is with respect to $x+ct$ not $x$.

Comment: If you integrate $F'(x + ct)$ with respect to $x$ you will have $\int_{x_0}^x F'(y+ct)dy = \int_{x_0+ct}^{x+ct}F'(z)dz = F(x+ct) - F(x_0+ct) $, but $\int_{x_0}^x F'(x+ct)d(x+ct) = F(x) - F(x_0)$, is that the confusion?

Comment: @Dayton Yes, exactly.

Comment: So evaluating this at $t=0$ gives you exactly what you want, does it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I now understand the confusion. So you know that
$$u(t,x) = F(t+cx) + G(t-cx)$$
and 
\begin{align}
\partial_t u(t,x) &= cF'(x + ct) - cG'(x - ct)
\end{align}
We then integrate with respect $x$ and evaluate at $t=0$, hence
\begin{align}
\int_{x_0}^x \partial_tu(t,y)dy|_{t=0} = \int_{x_0}^x \partial_tu(0,y)dy &= \int_{x_0}^x [cF'(y + ct) - cG'(y - ct)]dy|_{t=0} \\
&= \int_{x_0}^x cF'(y) - cG'(y)dy \\
&= c[F(x) - F(x_0)] - c[G(x) - G(x_0)]
\end{align}
Since you are integrating in $x$ it does not matter when you evaluate $t=0$. If you evaluate it after the integration then
\begin{align}
\int_{x_0}^x \partial_tu(t,y)dy|_{t=0} &= \int_{x_0}^x [cF'(y + ct) - cG'(y - ct)]dy|_{t=0} \\
&=\bigg(c\int_{x_0}^x F'(y + ct)dy - c\int_{x_0}^xG'(y - ct)dy\bigg)|_{t=0} \\
&=\bigg(c\int_{x_0+ct}^{x+ct} F'(y)dy - c\int_{x_0-ct}^{x-ct}G'(y)dy\bigg)|_{t=0} \\
&=\bigg(c[F(x+ct) - F(x_0 + ct)] - c[G(x-ct) - G(x_0 - ct)]\bigg)|_{t=0} \\
&=c[F(x) - F(x_0)] - c[G(x) - G(x_0)]
\end{align}

Which is the same thing. Let me know if this was the issue.

Comment: My problem is that $\int_{x_0}^x F'(\lambda)d\lambda = F(x) - F(x_0)$ when $F' = \frac{dF}{d\lambda}$ but here it's not true.

Comment: Also is it always correct that if we differentiate $F(x+ct)$ with respect to $x+ct$ and then evaluate that at $t = 0$ is same as evaluating $F(x+ct)$ at $t = 0$ and then differentiate with respect to $x$?

Comment: No, but $$\frac{d}{dt}F(x+ct) = c\frac{d}{dx}F(x+ct)= cF'(x+ct)$$ I think you are confusing $\frac{d}{dx}F(g(x))$ with $F'(g(x))$, these are not the same as we know from the chain rule.

Comment: According to chain rule it should be $\frac{d}{dt}F(x+ct) = c\frac{d}{d(x+ct)}F(x+ct)= cF'(x+ct)$